# Accessing options in single file Vue components

Tags: vue.js

Noob question. How do you access options in single file Vue components. Specifically the data. I want to push firebase data to this data. I can use `var self = this` and then reference `self` from within the firebase functions under the `created` function but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this?

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <navbar></navbar>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import ResourceInfo from './components/ResourceInfo'

// Import firebase

var db = firebase.database();
var auth = firebase.auth();

module.exports = {
  name: 'app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      users: {},
      currentUser: {},
      quizzes: {},
      resources: []
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    var self = this;
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // Get info for currently signed in user. 
        console.log(user);
        this.currentUser = user;
        console.log(this.currentUser);
      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
      }
    })
    // Import firebase data 
    var quizzesRef = db.ref('quizzes');
    quizzesRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
      this.quizzes = snapshot.val();
      console.log(this.quizzes);
    })

    var resourcesRef = db.ref('resources');
    resourcesRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
      this.resources.push(snapshot.val());
      console.log(this.resources);
    })

    var usersRef = db.ref('users');
    usersRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
      this.users = snapshot.val();
      console.log(this.users);
    })
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: Your use of the terms "options" and "data properties" are a little unclear. Can you be more specific about what specifically you think should be happening and what is happening instead?

Comment: I'm trying to access the `data` from within the firebase functions under the `created` hook. I set `var self = this;` at the beginning of the `created` function and that works but I'm wondering if there is another way to do this? I don't really like doing `self = this`. In the meantime I'll update my question to show you what I mean.

Comment: Yes, `self = this` is required in this case. You have a closure where `this` is no longer the VM.

Comment: I noticed this comment only after posting my answer below. Then you should start using `self.currentUser` instead of `this.currentUser`. Or you can simply start using arrow functions.

Comment: Arrow functions are an excellent solution - but aren't available everywhere yet: http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Comment: @DavidK.Hess Agreed, IE 11 is the real problem, as Vue.js supports IE 9.0 onwards. Opera Mini - I have no idea, there is nothing mentioned in [Vue.js github page](https://github.com/vuejs/vue)

Comment: I think the main consideration is whether Babel is in the tool chain or not. It has support for arrow functions that I think runs in all browsers. But I'm not a fan of transpiling.... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are asking about the data properties defined inside `data` of your Vue component.

You just have to do `this.users`, `this.currentUser`, `this.quizzes`, etc.

If you have trouble, it is probably because you are not using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) yet.

When you do function() {...}, it creates a new scope inside, and your `this` inside function is not the same as `this` of Vue component. Then you will not be able to set your data properties using `this.currentUser`, etc.

Instead you should use `() => {...}` - this works like function but does not create a scope inside.

If you have a function argument, you can do `response => {...}` or `(arg1, arg2) => {...}`

So, at all places within your Vue app, you can start doing as follows:

```js
created: function() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
            // Set this user info in Vue component, so it becomes visible to your template 
            this.currentUser = user;
            // and so on...
```

Let me know if this solves the issue.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. ES6 is something I should invest some time in as well. I know what I'll be doing this weekend. Thanks Mani for your help!

Comment: Yes, once you start using arrow functions as a habit for all anonymous functions, then you will never face these kinds of binding errors. If you look at some of the past questions on `vue.js` tag, a huge number of users face trouble because of this single issue :-)